# Creating array using loop

Tags: php, arrays

I need to create array using loop, How to do it

Here is my array

```
$data = array(
   value1 => 1,
   value2 => 32,
   value3 => 25
);

for (i=o,i<2,i++) {

}
```

If  `i` value is `2` my array should be like

```
$arrays = (array(data,data));
```

If `i` value is `3`my array should be like

```
$arrays=(array(data,data,data));
```

Help me to create array like this

If i i value is 2 means ouput should be like

```
result =(array(value1 => 1,value2 => 32,value3 => 25),(value1 => 1,value2 => 32,value3 => 25));
);
```

Comment: need to see real input and real desired output the psuedo-code is not helping us understand what your looking to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this:

```
<?php
$data = array(
   'value1' => 1,
   'value2' => 32,
   'value3' => 25
   );

$finalArr = [];

for ($i=0;$i<2;$i++) {
    $finalArr[] = $data;
}

print_r($finalArr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value1] => 1
            [value2] => 32
            [value3] => 25
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value1] => 1
            [value2] => 32
            [value3] => 25
        )

)
```

Your [Eval](https://eval.in/569268) sample

Answer (score 0):

So from what I understand, you want an array with a number of values...

```
$size = 5; # Size of the array
$array = array(); # The empty array to begin with
$value = array('value1' => '1', 'value2' => '32', 'value3' => '25');

// Create our array with a for loop
for($i=1; $i<=$size; $i++)
    array_push($array, $value);
```

The `var_dump` of the array would be:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["value1"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["value2"]=>
    string(2) "32"
    ["value3"]=>
    string(2) "25"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["value1"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["value2"]=>
    string(2) "32"
    ["value3"]=>
    string(2) "25"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["value1"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["value2"]=>
    string(2) "32"
    ["value3"]=>
    string(2) "25"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["value1"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["value2"]=>
    string(2) "32"
    ["value3"]=>
    string(2) "25"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    ["value1"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["value2"]=>
    string(2) "32"
    ["value3"]=>
    string(2) "25"
  }
}
```

Comment: Not numbre of values i mean number of arrays

Comment: If i i value is 2 means ouput should be like

 result =(array(value1 => 1,value2 => 32,value3 => 25),(value1 => 1,value2 => 32,value3 => 25));
);

Answer (score 0):

> below code give output as

```
<?php
$data = array(
   'value1' => 1,
   'value2' => 32,
   'value3' => 25
   );

$finalArr = [];

for ($i=1;$i<=3;$i++) {
    $finalArr['value'.$i] = $data['value'.$i];
}

print_r($finalArr);
?>
    Array
(
    [value1] => 1
    [value2] => 32
    [value3] => 25
)
```

> if you dont need value1 in side array ie [value1]=>1
>   then remove 'value'.$i from $finalArr['value'.$i]
>
> if you can change the value of $ according to the number of your array